# Triggering Dynamic Action on JavaScript fill

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, oracle-apex

I am developing form in Apex 4.1. I have address lookup field which uses Javascript to connect to address DB and paste lines of address into separate fields ( address1, addres2,town,postcode).

In the same page I have report that is showing guest records from our database and if it finds match (address that already exists in our guests database) it is showing it. I have few dynamic action on page which by Partial Refresh are updating results in the report. So, if someone put last_name, 'onChange' it will query our guests database and update results.

How , or which event should I choose to trigger partial report refresh if I have dynamically populated address fields from Javascript ?? So address lookup mechanism is returning and pasting address into fields and that change state of fields however Apex does not pick it up as 'onChange'. If i focus on the field and the leave field then it fires script properly.

Any help, greatly appreciated. Deadline is approaching !

Answer (score 0):

When changing items through javascript or jQuery, no change event will trigger. Dynamic actions with "set value" actions and action which fire on "change" will however trigger eachother even though they are javascript behind the scenes.
Since you are not using dynamic actions, you will need to trigger the change event yourself. When you have set the items with the new values, trigger it.
For example, using jQuery:

```
$("#P1_LAST_NAME").val(lNewValue).change();
```

Comment: I am using external API to retrieve address details which makes it quite difficult to 'listen' to changes because values are not being saved to session state, well not until SOMETHING in code would wake up and SAY 'oh snap there is new data in that field, I need to go and validate it against current addresses..' I need to find that something...

Comment: But you are retrieving data through that API. Are you not doing this through javascript? If so, then you do know when a change could happen to certain fields, as you will probably have to set these or provide them somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately not... there is only reference to external js link. during inital setup you select fields you want to populate and it kinda do all the work for you...

Comment: That is annoying. Does the API provide anything for you to hook into, such as a success callback? Is it an own api by any chance? You could always have a look in the actual js file and see if there is anything you could hook into or override. Without any of those options I suppose you're out of luck except for, in my opinion, weird or stupid solutions such as using a timer...